# Iterating through a map with doseq

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I'm doing some basic stuff from labrepl, now I want to write a function that will replace certain letters with other letters, for example: elosska → elößkä.

I wrote this:

```
(ns student.dialect (:require [clojure.string :as str]))
(defn germanize
  [sentence]
  (def german-letters {"a" "ä" "u" "ü" "o" "ö" "ss" "ß"})
  (doseq [[original-letter new-letter] german-letters]
    (str/replace sentence original-letter new-letter)))
```

but it doesn't work as I expect. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is my take,

```
(def german-letters {"a" "ä" "u" "ü" "o" "ö" "ss" "ß"})

(defn germanize [s]
  (reduce (fn[sentence [match replacement]]
            (str/replace sentence match replacement)) s german-letters))
```

```
(germanize "elosska")
```

Comment: Yeah, that's sweeter than mine. Very nice :-)

Comment: Yes, `reduce` is more functional and short, I just wanted to show where the problem arise...

Comment: Wow, took me a bit to grok this one, that's one clever use of reduce and argument destructuring ! I could use the technique right away on some of my own code. Really wish there was a book with functional 'patterns' like this one.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 problems here:

1. `doseq` doesn't preserve head of list that created by its evaluation, so you won't get any results
2. `str/replace` works on separate copies of text, producing 4 different results - you can check this by replacing `doseq` with `for` and you'll get list with 4 entries.

You code could be rewritten following way:

```
(def german-letters {"a" "ä" "u" "ü" "o" "ö" "ss" "ß"})
(defn germanize [sentence]
  (loop [text sentence
         letters german-letters]
    (if (empty? letters)
      text
      (let [[original-letter new-letter] (first letters)]
        (recur (str/replace text original-letter new-letter)
               (rest letters))))))
```

In this case, intermediate results are collected, so all replacements are applied to same string, producing correct string:

```
user> (germanize "elosska")
"elößkä"
```

P.S. it's also not recommended to use `def` in the function - it's better to use it for top-level forms

Comment: Hamza Yerlikaya provides solution in functional style - `reduce` is very handy when you need to collect intermediate results...

Answer (score 6):

Alex has of course already correctly answered the question with respect to the original issue using `doseq`... but I found the question interesting and wanted to see what a more "functional" solution would look like. And by that I mean without using a loop.

I came up with this:

```
(ns student.dialect (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn germanize [sentence]
  (let [letters {"a" "ä" "u" "ü" "o" "ö" "ss" "ß"}
        regex (re-pattern (apply str (interpose \| (keys letters))))]
    (str/replace sentence regex letters)))
```

Which yields the same result:

```
student.dialect=> (germanize "elosska")
"elößkä"
```

The `regex (re-pattern...` line simply evaluates to `#"ss|a|o|u"`, which would have been cleaner, and simpler to read, if entered as an explicit string, but I thought it best to have only one definition of the german letters.

Comment: I'd say that this is the way to go, especially if performance is of concern at all. It only performs a single replacement and builds up a single string (using `StringBuffer`), whereas `loop`-ing or `reduce`-ing over the map of replacements will construct one new string per replacement and always go over the entire string from the previous step. Also, since all the solutions presented (rightly) use `clojure.string/replace` which is a built-in which can handle the whole operation in one call, it should be allowed to handle it. Plus, this basically reads like the problem statement. +1.

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming in the above that the replacements never introduce patterns in need of further processing. This is the case here, but if it were not, then that would be a completely different problem requiring further clarification (e.g. is the whole operation meant to be idempotent? if not, how should the pattern/replacement pairs be ordered? is it still ok to use a map to hold them?). Just an aside... :-)

Comment: @Michał Thanks for your comment. I wasn't aware of the performance implications of reduce, and so I've learned something valuable today (and still got a lot of Clojure to learn!).